# How to return a buffer from a R ggplot graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If you have a ggplot graphic, for example:

```
graphic <- ggplot(data.df, aes(x = Axis1, y = Axis2, shape = Plant, color = Type)) + geom_point(size = 5)
```

Can you transform this graphic in a string buffer with the binary content of a png? How achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to explain a bit more about what you're trying to do.  the object `graphic` is just an object in R.  It doesn't exist on disk and is not yet a `png` or any other file type... In addition to that, you'll need to explain how you want to "transform" the png and what you mean by a string buffer.

Comment: I think that is a little obviously. I know that graphic is a object, and for example when you do: ggsave(filename="example.png", plot=graphic), you can obtain a graphic in disk. So this function in some point write the object in disk in a image format. I am needing this intermediate step, because I suppose that for save the plot you need the buffer. I need the buffer representation of this image.

Comment: What remains unclear is what you are expecting that you are not finding the `graphic` objet and not in the `example.png` binary?

Comment: It's clunky, but perhaps it would be easiest to write the PNG file to disk and then use `readBin`?  Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Ok Ben, I think that you understand my problem and my first approach was the same as you suggest. I need to avoid this, because my problem is use ggplot from an external language: nodejs. In nodejs doesnt exist a powerfull tool to do stadistical graphics.

Comment: There is a package, 'raster', that may be what you need, but I think the question should be closed as too vague at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps `con <- socketConnection(...)` would allow you pass data between R and nodejs. Most R functions will accept `con` in place of a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have sent an image to the `png()` device either with `png("myfile.png); print(myplot); dev.off()` or with `ggsave()` there is only the raster data. You can retrieve that data with readPNG from the png package:

```
library(png)
img.n <- readPNG(file.choose(), TRUE)
```

The numbers are all less than 0:

```
> str(img.n)
 'nativeRaster' int [1:480, 1:480] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
 - attr(*, "channels")= int 4
> max(img.n)
[1] -1
> head(img.n[img.n < -1] )
[1]  -2105377  -3487030  -4342339  -1250068  -6184543 -10329502
```